# How to process signals & events properly from long running task in a QThread

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a thread that runs a server in QT. The server runs in a polling loop until its told to stop. I'd like to be able to add slots to my class so I can do stuff such as stop the server from a signal.

QT seems to have a pretty convoluted history with QThread so I've been reading up on blogs about doing threads right and this is what I've come up with.

MyServer is a class derived from QObject:

```
class MyServer : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

public slots:
  void run();
  void stop();

signals:
  void finished();

private:
  void init();
  void pollForConnections(int ms);
  void cleanup();
};
```

I can run the server from a thread by creating my object, creating a QThread, moving the server to the thread's ownership, connecting up some signals and invoking start():

```
MyServer *server = new MyServer();
QThread *serverThread = new QThread();
server.moveToThread(serverThread);
// Cause thread to delete itself when server finishes
QObject::connect(serverThread, SIGNAL(started()), server, SLOT(run()));
QObject::connect(server, SIGNAL(finished()), serverThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
serverThread->start();
```

So when the QThread starts it emits a started() signal and my run() slot is invoked by the started() signal. The run() method is a loop which spins around until it is told to stop:

```
void MyServer::run() {
  init();
  while (true) {
    {
      QMutexLocker lock(&mutex_);
      if (stop_) {
        break;
      }
    }
    pollForConnections(100); // 100ms is timeout
  }
  cleanup();
  emit finished();
}

void MyServer::stop() {
  QMutexLocker lock(&mutex_);
  stop_ = true;
}
```

The issue here of course is that started() will not return to the QThread because it's in my loop. And since my loop has no processing for signals, I couldn't connect stop() to another signal. So presently I just invoke stop() from any thread and use a mutex to protect the flag while I do.

QT has a QEventLoop which I could modify the loop:

```
QEventLoop eventLoop;
while (true) {
    if (stop_) {
      break;
    }
    pollForConnections(100); // 100ms is timeout
    eventLoop.processEvents();
  }
```

So potentially I could hook stop() to a signal of some kind and I don't need a mutex to protect stop_ because it will be run on my own thread. I could also process events as I spin around.

This appears to function but I wonder if this is good practice - don't forget that I'm still hanging off that started() signal so are there reentrancy problems here? Also, once I drop out of my loop, is the QThread going to drop into it's default exec() and then run forever? Is it sufficient that by emitting finished() and invoking deleteLater() that the thread will sort itself out properly?

Comment: If you want to handle SLOTs in your thread, you have 2 options : Call  `processEvents()` repeatedly or call `exec()` which in turn calls `processEvents()` repeatedly.

Comment: That's what I thought - as above. Just wondering if there is a reason not to given that effectively all my code is running from a slot called run() invoked from the thread's existing processEvents().

Answer (score 1):

You'd have a better design if you just used QThread's default run() method, and signals-and-slots as your mechanism for everything.

In particular, instead of having a mutex and a polled boolean, you can connect a signal to the thread's quit() method, and when you want the thread to go away, just emit that signal.

Also, there's almost certainly a better way to check for connections than polling for them.  The problem with polling (in this case anyway) is that it blocks execution of the thread's other duties for up to 100mS, which will make the thread perform slowly.  It also means the thread is using up some CPU cycles every 100mS, even when 99% of the time no connections are actually incoming.  Assuming these are TCP connections, check out the [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsocketnotifier.html) and/or [QTCPServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html) classes, either of which can handle incoming TCP connections without polling.

> Also, once I drop out of my loop, is the QThread going to drop into
>   it's default exec() and then run forever?

Only if you explicitly call up to QThread::run().

> Is it sufficient that by emitting finished() and invoking deleteLater() that the thread will sort itself out properly

It might work, but I think calling QThread::quit() or QThread::exit() (and using the default event loop) would be a better practice.

Comment: The problem here is that the server is a 3rd party lib and I can't change the way it's designed. It polls on a loop so my code must run this way. And if I override run() on QThread then I run afoul of best practice in QT which has spawned dozens of blog posts on the subject.

Comment: So don't override run().  If you absolutely have to poll, you could set up a QTimer to emit a signal at regular intervals, and call pollForConnections() from the slot that the QTimer's timeout() signal is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

MyServer.h

```
class MyServer : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:

  bool isRuning() const;
public slots:
  void run();
  void stop();

signals:
  void finished();

private:
  void init();

  //don't need in this method
  //void pollForConnections(int ms);

  void cleanup();

  mutable QMutex m_mutex;
};
```

MyServer.cpp

```
void MyServer::run() {
  init();
  while (isRuning()) {
    //some code here with signals
  }
  cleanup();
  emit finished();
}

void MyServer::stop() {
  QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
  stop_ = true;
}
bool isRuning() const {
  QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
  return stop_;
}
```

1. You don't need in QEventLoop. All signals from your infinite loop in while queued to the main thread events queue, if exist connection with object from main thread.
2. run method calling not from main thread, his call also queued to separate event queue.
3. After finished signal, serverTread object is queued for deleting via deleteLater method.

Comment: The issue is not the signals I emit but the slots() I want to receive on. e.g. if I hooked stop() up to a button via a signal then the button click is on one thread and I'm on another. I could hack the connect to be direct, using a mutex to protect the flag but it doesn't seem clean, particularly as I might have other slots I want to add. It would be safer to the thread if the slots were invoked on my thread with a queue which means I have to process it.

Comment: @locka, from separate thread signals always connected via Qt::QueuedConnection. It mean that slots calling occur in event, not directly, and in separate thread.

Comment: This will not work due to the spinlock in `run()` method. It will never find a chance to process the events in the queue.